# Change botman question button color style

Tags: laravel, botman

I want to change the color of the button inside the botman chatbot widget.

Here is the code:

```
        $question = Question::create('Hi, I am virutal assistant. How can i help today?')
        ->callbackId('select_service')
        ->addButtons([
            Button::create('I am waiting to bid on the property')->value('Bid')->additionalParameters(
                ['background' => 'red !important',
                    'color' => 'negative']
            ),
            Button::create('I would like to watch the auction and be
            notified when the auction starts')->value('Spa'),
            Button::create('I would like the auction results sent to me')->value('Beauty'),
            Button::create('I am interesting in selling my house and would like to see
            what the market is doing')->value('Beauty'),
            Button::create('I am looking to purchase a property')->value('Beauty'),
        ]);
```

[I want to change the color of these buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvMTo.png)